# RadAjaxManager problem when showing/hiding control on page loading

Tags: telerik, radajaxmanager

I have the webform with dropdown list, label and textbox. Like below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList> 

<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="Some text">
</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="edtTest" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
```

I want to show/hide label and text box depending on the value selected on dropdown list. So I've added RadAjaxManader:

```
<rad:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">  
    <AjaxSettings>   
        <rad:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ddlTest">   
            <UpdatedControls> 
                <rad:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lblTest" /> 
                <rad:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="edtTest" /> 
            </UpdatedControls> 
        </rad:AjaxSetting> 
    </AjaxSettings> 
</rad:RadAjaxManager>
```

and procedure "SetupVisibility" which takes value from the dropdown list, does some walidations and desides whether to show or hide the label and the text box. When I use the procedure like this:

```
Protected Sub ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlTest.SelectedIndexChanged  
    SetupVisibility()  
End Sub
```

it works good, but now I want to call SetupVisibility when the page is loaded:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    SetupVisibility()
End Sub
```

The problem occurs in such a scenario:

1. SetupVisibility() hides textbox and label while page is loaded.
2. I change value on ddlTest dropdown list.
3. SetupVisibility() wants to show textbox and label, but then **I get the error**: `Microsoft JScript - runtime error: Cannot update control with ID: ctl00_CPH1_lblTest. The control does not exist.` Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the problem. I've wrapped the textbox and the label into div and panel:

```
<div id="panelTest_DIV" runat="server">
  <asp:Panel ID="panelTest" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="Some text..."></asp:Label><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="edtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

and AjaxManager:

```
<rad:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ddlTest">
  <UpdatedControls>
    <rad:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="panelTest_DIV" />
  </UpdatedControls>
</rad:AjaxSetting>
```

inside `SetupVisibility()` I set `panelTest.Visibility`. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Page_Init is fired when the page is initialising. During this event there is no guarentee that the controls have been created..

Try putting your code in the Page_Load as controls are guaranteed to have been created by then.

Comment: I already do it in Page_Load. I've just made a mistake in my question. Corrected.